# Lumen select specific file as default router based on request

Tags: php, laravel, customization, lumen

Everything is working fine in my application, but I want to select a default router file based on Illuminate\Http\Request $request object.

I made 2 files for this in the routes folder:

[image]

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

$colors = ["Blue", "Red", "Orange", "Black", "White", "Golden",
    "Green", "Purple", "Yellow", "cyan",
    "Gray", "Pink", "Brown", "Sky Blue", "Silver"];
$router->get('/', ["as" => "home", function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) use ($colors) {
    if ($request->getHttpHost() === 'color1.tk') {
        $limit = count($colors) - 1;
        return view('index')->with("color", $colors[rand(0, $limit)]);

    }else{
        return "This action is not allowed";
    }
}]);

$router->get('/{color}', function ($color) use ($colors) {
    dd(array_search(strtolower($color), array_map("strtolower", $colors)));
});
```

web.php:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

$colors = ["Blue", "Red", "Orange", "Black", "White", "Golden",
    "Green", "Purple", "Yellow", "cyan",
    "Gray", "Pink", "Brown", "Sky Blue", "Silver"];
$router->get('/', ["as" => "home", function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) use ($colors) {
    if ($request->getHttpHost() === 'localhost') {
 return " yayy this is working on localhost "    
}
}]);
```

this is color1.php:

```
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/color1.php';
});
```

Comment: Can you detail what do you want more exactely?

Comment: @betontalpfa i just want to explore laravel core way to register routes to customize laravel routing system . I want to accomplish is that i need single page for my domain that why i choose lumen light weight :) . So i have many ways to accomplish this task but i want to do it official way by using app instance :)